# Unable to throw exception in Intelj Debug Mode

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, try-catch, intellij-14

I am debugging a piece of code where I need to throw an exception in try block so that the control goes to catch block. When I am running app using intellij debug mode, when I throw exception by clicking on frame in debugger mode, I see the exception is not getting thrown and the code flow is working normal.What is the reason for this?

```
try
{
ApiRequest apiRequest = new ApiRequest();
..........
...........

return invoke();
} catch(NoHttpResponseException ex) {
   // debug here
      }
    }
```

I have debug points in try block. At any point, i click on debug frame and click throw exception and I type `new NoHttpResponseException()`, but the catch is not called and the flow after next statement continues.What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to simply put the statement inside the try block (so in the source code rather than injecting the exception with IntelliJ)?

Comment: it will work, but wanted to know why intelj not throwing.I have to change code and build again otherwise ,because hotswap wont work due to some reasons

Answer (score 0):

I wrote similar code as a web service in Intellij Idea and it worked as expected.
Here is the code and debug run.

[image]

When I go to 'Frames' context menu while debugging and press Throw Exception action I can throw exception when the cursor is in inside invoke method, but  in exceptionExample method the same action does not throw exception. It steps into the code.
There may be a bug.

Comment: I dont know why its not working for me. Are there any restrictions on type of exception we can throw?

Comment: No I don't think so. If you send more code I can try it on my computer. Are you sure that invoke method throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Throw Exception** action from the 'Frames' context menu:
[image]